# Javascripts that come from tagmanager

Tags: javascript

I want to establish if Javascripts are being loaded by being explicity called from a page or via a tag manager.

The following code can be used to list the Javascripts a page is runnning

```
$("script[src]").each(function( i, src ) 
{  
       console.info($(this).attr('src'));  
});
```

The following script is an example of a tag manager:

```
www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=GTM-TM2FVV7
d3c3cq33003psk.cloudfront.net/opentag-136914-2122355.js
```

How could I determine which scripts are brought it by a tag manager service and which are called explicitly in the page?

I considered manually going through the HTML source code and note which scripts are explicitly called. However, the problem is then how do I know which of the scripts called by which tag manager.

Comment: I also tried looking at the preview code from the Network Tab in Chrome Dev tools on the tag manager scripts. Its very hard to see what is going on although it is clear some .js files are being referenced in the code. An indication of a script being brought it but not conclusivve

Comment: Can you use the `src` itself to discern? I mean, if the tag includes `googletagmanager`.

Comment: Also about the garbage you find while inspecting script, that's a minimized form of the script. Most browsers have a pretty print button that helps a little. Its icon usually is two curly brackets `{}`.

Comment: @David González not sure what you mean by "Can you use the src itself to discern". Can you rephrase?

Comment: One option i thought of is to use the Chrome Sources tab to pause the script at the point of bringing in the tag manager scripts and see what subsequent scripts then load. However, if the tag manager has logic that says only load this script once the Page Load event fires or something to that effect then i will still be no better off

Comment: I meant to use the attribute `src`. If the script comes from `googletagmanager.com` then it's trivial to see if `src` includes that string (`$(this).attr('src').indexOf('googletagmanager') != -1`). For this to work you need that all the scripts that are tag managers come from that domain and not locally.

Comment: The tag manager will bring in scripts from other domains so i don't see how that will work.

Comment: The Initiator column in Google Developer Tools seems to give the information I want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to "listen" to changes occurring in your DOM tree. In your case you are interested in `<script>` nodes added to your page.

Here's a proof of concept:

1. The initial page contains `<script src="http://example.com/internal.js"></script>` so that one shouldn't be seen as an external script.
2. The `dropScript` function simulates your tag manager: it will drop an external `<script>` on your page, which we'll track.
3. The observer callback gets executed each time a change in your DOM occurs. In this case, I'll be interested in additions of `<script>` elements only.
4. After 1s, I dump to the console all the external scripts detected so far.

```js
const dropScript = (src) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    document.body.appendChild(
      document.createElement('script'))
        .src = src;
    console.log(`dropped ${src} on the page`);
  }, 500);
};

const externalScript = [];

const observer = new MutationObserver((mutations) => {
  for (let mutation of mutations) {
    mutation.addedNodes.forEach((node) => {
      if (node.nodeName.toLowerCase() === 'script') {
        externalScript.push(
          node.getAttribute('src'));
      }
    });
  }
});

observer.observe(document.body, { childList: true });

dropScript('http://example.com/external_1.js');
dropScript('http://example.com/external_2.js');
dropScript('http://example.com/external_3.js');

setTimeout(() => {
  console.log(externalScript);
}, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="http://example.com/internal.js"></script>
```